# onClickListner with for loop not working

Tags: java, android, for-loop, increment

variable i is not incrementing, if answer is right then i want to ask another question by incrementing variable i. i implemented OnClickListner but nothing is happening. i am new to android, thank you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

        ImageView car, icecream, pencil, umbrella, ball;
        TextView question, answer;
        int i, size, j;
        final String[] objects  = {"car", "icecream", "pencil", "ball","umbrella"};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           final Animation expandIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.expand_in);




            size = objects.length;
            car = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.car);

            umbrella = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.umbrella);

            icecream = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icecream);

            pencil = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pencil);

            ball = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ball);

            question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
            answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);

            j=0;
            for (i=0; i < size; i++)

            {

                if(i == j){
                    question.setText("");
                    question.setText("Where is "+objects[i]+" ?");
                    car.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            if("car"==objects[i]){
                                answer.setText("Right Answer");
                                answer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                                j++;
                                car.startAnimation(expandIn);


                            } else {
                                answer.setText("Wrong Answer");
                                answer.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                                answer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        answer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    }
                                }, 2000);

                            }

                        }
                    });

                    icecream.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            if("icecream"==objects[i]){
                                answer.setText("Right Answer");
                                j++;

                            } else {
                                answer.setText("Wrong Answer");
                                answer.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                                answer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        answer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    }
                                }, 2000);

                            }

                        }
                    });

                    pencil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            if("pencil"==objects[i]){
                                answer.setText("Right Answer");
                                j++;
                            } else {
                                answer.setText("Wrong Answer");
                                answer.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                                answer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        answer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    }
                                }, 2000);

                            }

                        }
                    });


                    ball.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            if("ball"==objects[i])

                            {
                                answer.setText("Right Answer");
                                j++;

                            } else {
                                answer.setText("Wrong Answer");
                                answer.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                                answer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        answer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    }
                                }, 2000);

                            }

                        }
                    });


                    umbrella.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            if("umbrella"==objects[i]){
                                answer.setText("Right Answer");
                                j++;

                            } else {
                                answer.setText("Wrong Answer");
                                answer.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                                answer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        answer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    }
                                }, 2000);

                            }

                        }
                    });





                }
                j = j+1;
                break;

           }


    }
```

Comment: You can't set OnClickListener() inside loop.. Iterate loop inside OnClickListener() method.

Comment: Your above problem can be solved without loop. Also a loop won't work over interface's methods. Reason is your loop has already been executed but your `OnClickListener()` was never called. So in the end you will always get max value of the loop

Comment: According to your code "j++" will happens only when onClick call thats why i==j will work only once later i never equal to j so it never enter inside of if(){........}

Comment: Thanks for the reply, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks everyone, I solved it by iterating loop inside OnClickListener() method. thanks for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking from the for loop after `j = j+1`